# ClickOnce 2010 and Creating a Desktop Icon and Start Menu Group

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, clickonce

We have an application that we distribute via ClickOnce. The user base used to have Power User rights on their machines and the Desktop icon and Start Menu Group would be created every time.

Since the operations team took away Power User rights, the desktop icon and the start menu group is not being created.

What machine rights are needed in order to be able to create both a Desktop icon and a Start menu group in Windows XP ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The user only needs to be able to read and write to their own profile to be able to create the desktop shortcut and a start menu group.

Note that ClickOnce won't do anything that requires administrative privileges.